# Distinct record using linq in entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

According to this query i get all records which have same id but i want only one time that record

```
var query = (from c in CompObj.EmpInfoes
                     join d in CompObj.Leaves on c.EmpID equals d.ProjectManagerID
                     where c.RoleID == 4 || c.RoleID == 2
                     select new { c.EmpName, c.EmpID });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = (from c in CompObj.EmpInfoes
             join d in CompObj.Leaves on c.EmpID equals d.ProjectManagerID
             where c.RoleID == 4 || c.RoleID == 2
             select new { c.EmpName, c.EmpID })
    .Distinct();
```

Or was there something more you needed?

Answer (score 2):

Just add .Distinct() at the end.